# Best practice for serving static files

Tags: python, file, static, nginx, serving

I am developing on a python webserver (Tornado). I plan to place this in a production instance with nginx in front. This will be my first time placing something into a production environment on my own. My question is how to setup files/directories for static serving. For instance my application, allows users to upload photos to the web. I recieve the requests in Tornado, and save to disk. However when a user visits their items page, I would rather the images be pulled from a static server. My question is what is the best practice for getting the images from my dynamic server to the static server? Do I rsync the image directory to the static server, then run a cron that delete the images from the dynamic server?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is use shared storage, but if can't use it, than you can use "proxy_store" option from nginx. Example from nginx doc:

```
location /images/ {
    root                 /data/www;
    error_page           404 = @fetch;
}

location @fetch {
    internal;

    proxy_pass           http://backend;
    proxy_store          on;
    proxy_store_access   user:rw  group:rw  all:r;
    proxy_temp_path      /data/temp;

    root                 /data/www;
}
```

Comment: Could you describe the setup for shared storage..I googled around, but couldn't find an example of how it would be done. Don't need something concrete, pseudo example would work great!

Comment: any network file system can be used as shared storage. NFS for example.

Comment: Also some companies use WebDAV as protocol for upload files to shared storage.